# how to extract a portion of string from the end in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, slice

I have this `url https://something.io/room2` I need to extract "room2" or whatever that comes after the last "/", thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const str = "https://something.io/room2";
const splitArr = str.split('/');
const lastStr = splitArr[splitArr.length - 1];
console.log(lastStr);
```

Comment: Glad it help :)